# First icon gets hidden in taskbar notification area

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

I'm experiencing a bizarre issue with the taskbar notification area in Windows 10 1909. I only just noticed this issue but I have no idea how long it's been happening since I didn't pay too much attention to the notification area before.

If I only enable a single icon in the notification area then everything is fine, the one icon is displayed in the notification area. But if I enable two or more icons, then all the icons are displayed except for the first one, which is replaced by an empty space.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

I actually have three icons enabled, but there's an empty space where the first one should be, between the two icons and the input method selector (the ENG DV thing).

I experience this issue regardless of which icons I choose; as long as I've enabled more than one, the first one I enable is hidden, while the others are correctly displayed. The same is true even if I put the taskbar on the right or left side of the screen, so that it's verti

I have tried deleting the  "IconStreams" and "PasticonsStream" keys in \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify, which I've seen suggested in a number of places, but this had no effect.

I haven't been able to find any mention of this issue on the internet, let alone a solution, so I'd greatly appreciate any help here.

EDIT: another thing I noticed, in case it helps diagnose the problem: if, when dragging a new icon onto the notification area, my mouse cursor is on the blank space when I let go of the mouse button, I see this weird UI element in the space where the first icon should be:

[image]

As soon as the mouse leaves that space it goes away and goes back to being an empty space.

Comment: Try making your clock just the small clock. Then it fits on one small line and I think your space in the system tray will normalize. I think the large (expanded) clock format is doing this.

Comment: @John Hmm so I couldn't find a way to make the clock smaller other than enabling "Use small taskbar settings" in Taskbar settings, but that didn't help. I also tried disabling the clock altogether (as well as the input indicator) but that didn't help either.

Comment: Try this article  https://www.thewindowsclub.com/display-seconds-in-taskbar-clock-windows

Comment: If you don't mind the change in appearance, increase the Taskbar height to two or three full rows.

Comment: @John I tried the registry tweak in that article and it didn't do anything (i.e., it didn't even show seconds in the clock). Also the article itself can't even seem to make up its mind about what it wants to suggest...

Comment: @DrMoishePippik unfortunately I do mind the change in appearance... But, interestingly enough, even if I change the taskbar height there's still a bit of an issue: with three full rows I can display up to three icons, but then if I display four or more icons, then the rightmost column of icons isn't displayed.

Comment: Anyway in terms of workarounds it's pretty easy to just pick an icon I don't really care about, and pick it as the first enabled one so that all the ones I do care about get properly displayed, but I'd prefer to properly solve this if possible...

Comment: Try making your Task Bar one icon high. That will help you determine if there is a spacing issue. The clock has to change for this to happen.

Comment: @John as I mentioned above I already tried making the taskbar small, which makes the taskbar one icon high and also makes the clock smaller, and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Try Windows 10 Repair  (Microsoft Media Creation Link)

Comment: @John ...No. Like sure, that would probably work, but if I can't find a specific solution to this I'm more inclined to just work around it rather than effectively reinstalling my OS.

Comment: A Repair Install is NOT a fresh install.  Select Keep Everything and you will not lose anything, but it fixes many issues.  Once the download is done, it is about an hour of watching paint dry.

Comment: Yeah I know I don't lose files/apps from doing a repair install, but there are a number of things that do get lost, like various registry settings (just to be clear, none of it taskbar-related stuff that seems likely to be relevant to this issue) so it really is kind of a pain to deal with.